# how do i or can i select existing rows from one table that match condition but select from other table if the colum has value?

Tags: sql

Hi all i have one table with columns host, vulnerability and other table with colums host, vulnerability, action.

I want to select from table 1 where host=192.168.0.1 and vulnerability=10 but if in table 2 exists a register with same condition i don't like the row of table 1, i want the row of table 2 includo g the action column.

What do you suggest temporary table, don't exists ?

I test some single select query but may be is impossible with just one query.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
SELECT
    a.Host,
    CASE
        WHEN a.Vulnerability = b.Vulnerability THEN b.Vulnerability
        ELSE a.Vulnerability
    END [Vulnerability],
    CASE
        WHEN a.Vulnerability = b.Vulnerability THEN b.[Action]
        ELSE 'N/A'
    END [Action]
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b
ON b.Host = a.Host
```

You can run the following code to see an example:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tableA') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tableA

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tableB') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tableB

CREATE TABLE #tableA (
    Host VARCHAR(25),
    Vulnerability INT )

CREATE TABLE #tableB (
    Host VARCHAR(25),
    Vulnerability INT,
    [Action] VARCHAR(10) )

INSERT INTO #tableA (Host,Vulnerability)
    SELECT '192.168.0.1',10 UNION
    SELECT '192.168.0.2',5

INSERT INTO #tableB (Host,Vulnerability,Action)
    SELECT '192.168.0.1',10,'WHATEVER' UNION
    SELECT '192.168.0.2',0,'NONE'

SELECT
    a.Host,
    CASE
        WHEN a.Vulnerability = b.Vulnerability THEN b.Vulnerability
        ELSE a.Vulnerability
    END [Vulnerability],
    CASE
        WHEN a.Vulnerability = b.Vulnerability THEN b.[Action]
        ELSE 'N/A'
    END [Action]
FROM #tableA a
INNER JOIN #tableB b
ON b.Host = a.Host
```

The above code will return rows from table B, including Action, that match in table A. If there is no match, it will return only the row in table A.